# How to use different permission level when breaking permissions for current user in SP2013 REST api?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, rest

I am using SP2013 rest api to break permissions using this tutorial:

http://spsite.pro/Blog/Post/3/SharePoint-2013-REST-API-%E2%80%93-How-to-set-Unique-Permissions-(Item-Level-Permissions)

When I break permissions, and I have copyroleassignments=false, then it puts the current user with full control. Is there a way I can change that full control to something else.

To be specific, I would like a permission level where they can add/edit/delete items in the list, but not add/delete/edit columns. Also can't delete or create a list.

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a group with a custom permission level?

Comment: I can make groups, and I can make custom permissions, but problem is how to make default permission different when breaking permission using rest

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a custom SPRole beforehand
2. `/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('YourList')/breakroleinheritance` with `copyRoleAssignments = false`
3. `/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('YourList')/roleassignments/getbyprincipalid` get remaining records and delete them
4. `/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('YourList')/roleassignments/addroleassignment` with required `principalid` and `roleDefId = id of your SPRole`

[This article at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495392.aspx) is about solving something similar, I suppose